# decoding a character array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm

Given a character array in a URL format like

```
   char *s="www.google.com\tsp finite.aspx"
```

While decoding it space should be replaced by %20 and thus the string becomes:

```
   char *s="www.google.com\tsp%20finite.aspx"
```

We are not allowed to use a new character array but allowed to use some character variables for temporary use. Should not use any containers also. The array contains enough space to contain the decoded data so no need to worry about the more space to be taken.

I followed the Brute-Force mechanism where all the characters from the point of finding a space to the end of the array are to be swapped. But this is not the most efficient way to solve the problem.

Can any body tell me which is the best way (algorithm) to decrease the no. of swappings in order to acquire the solution.

Comment: Why not title this post as "please do my homework"

Comment: @EdHeal While seem to be HW, the OP has already indicated what he has tried, and described why it fails (not efficient enough) - there is no problem with HW question as long as the OP shows effort, and it does.

Comment: So where is the code for the attempt

Comment: "We are not allowed to use a new character array". So where will you store the result? In place of the original string? Is there guarantee that there is enough space in the array to grow the string?

Comment: @EdHeal This is an algorithm question, and he has given his algorithm, it seems fine to me. I believe SantoshSahu also expects an algorithimc answer, and not a ready to run one.

Comment: @EdHeal: Greyed out the approach, hope you now understand my approach. Thanks for having patience.

Comment: And remember that modifying a string literal is _undefined behavior_. `char *s = "..."` vs `char s[] = "..."` vs `char s[1000] = "..."`.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the string has been allocated using `malloc`

First calculate the number of spaces and the length of the string

Then the new length = old length + number of spaces * 2. Use realloc to expand the string.

The work backwards from the end and copy to the new length. When encountering space copy in %20 instead.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem could be that swapping space with %20 will require moving the whole string 2 characters more .

Here's an idea :

1. Parse the whole string once, and count the number of spaces in the string
2. The new length of the array would be strlen(original) + 2*(nOfSpaces) (let's call it from now on NewLen)
3. Parse the whole string once again but starting backwards.
4. You will copy the previous string contents inside itself but at an offset until you hit a space

   - you will have a pointer starting at strlen(original) and one starting at NewLen
   - parse from strlen(original) backwards until you find a space (the substrLen will be subLen)
   - memcpy from [strlen(original)-curParsingindex] to [NewLen - curParsingIndex-2*(enteredSpaces)] sublen amount
5. Instead of copying the space, put %20 instead

This way you will avoid moving the string forward each time you hit a space.

Regarding step 4 , you might think about using a temporary variable for the sublen, since you might end up writing in the same memory zone by mistake (take an example where all the spaces are at the beginning).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two passes. The key idea is to first count the number of spaces and then move each character directly to its final position. In your approach you shift the remainder of the string at each occurrence of a space.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[1000] = "www.example.com/hello world !";
    int length;
    int spaces;
    int i;
    char *ptr;

    printf ("\"%s\"\n", str);

    // pass 1:
    // calculate length and count spaces
    length = 0;
    spaces = 0;
    for (ptr = str; *ptr; ptr++) {
        if (*ptr == ' ') {
            spaces++;
        }
        length++;
    }

    // pass 2:
    // transform string
    // preserve terminating null character
    ptr = str + length + 2 * spaces;
    for (i = length; i >= 0; i--) {
        char c = str[i];

        if (c == ' ') {
            *ptr-- = '0';
            *ptr-- = '2';
            *ptr-- = '%';
        }
        else {
            *ptr-- = c;
        }
    }

    printf ("\"%s\"\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic interview coding question; a good solution for this starts with a good interface for your solution. Something that works is:

```
char* replaceChar(char* in, char c)

char *in - string you want to decode
c - the char you want to replace with it's hexa value ASCII code ( HEX val ascii for ' ' is 0x20)
```

Pseudocode:

1. allocate a buffer the same size as the input buffer
2. get the index of the first occurrence of the char you want to replace (strcspn can help with that)
3. copy the content of the of the input up to the found index to the new buffer.
4. reallocate the new buffer size to `newSize=oldSize+2`
5. add % to the new string
6. repeat until you reach the end of the string.
7. return a pointer to the new string

You can also do it in place on the original string but that solution is a bit more complicated because you have to shift everything.